# Node.js при попытке скачать PDF файл он не понимает кириллицу

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Работаю в Node.js, PostgreSQL,Express.

Пытаюсь скачать PDF-файл со своего localhost. Вроде бы файл скачивает и открывается без проблем, но он понимает только латиницу, а если добавить данные кириллицы он будет его писать какими-то символами. Такой вопрос как сделать, чтобы понимало кириллицу ?

Использую пакет `pdfkit`.

```
const pdf  = require('pdfkit');
var myDoc = new pdf;

const download1 =(req,res) => {
  
    
    const db = new pg.Pool(admin_role.client_admin)

    db.connect(function(err, client, done){
        console.log("admin")  
        if(err){
            return console.error('Соединение не удалось')
        }
        client.query(admin_role.accounting_wokr_transport, function(err, result1){
           if (err){
           res.end()
           return console.error("Запрос не удался")
           }
           
           done()


           console.log(result1);
           myDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream( '12345.pdf'));                                  //creates pdf with the name of the user
           var print=0;
           myDoc.font('Helvetica'); 
           myDoc.fontSize(30);
           myDoc.text('Dear ' + 'Marina' + ',' , 50 , 50 );
           myDoc.fontSize(20);
           myDoc.text(' ');
           myDoc.text('You have paid an amount of INR ' + 1111 + '/- to our organisation.' );
           myDoc.fontSize(15);
           myDoc.fillColor('red');
           myDoc.text('This money will be used by us to provide free eduction to the poor children.');
           myDoc.text(' ');
           myDoc.fillColor('green');
           myDoc.text('Your contribution will be remembered and recognised, as of the following other donors:');
           var k=1;
           console.table(result1.rows[0].address)
           myDoc.text('почему не понимаешь кириллицу ?',{lang:'ru'});

                setTimeout(function(){  var data =fs.readFileSync('./'+ '12345.pdf', {root: __dirname});
           res.contentType("application/pdf");
           res.send(data);
           end=1;
           
       },3000);
                setTimeout( function(){res.end();}, 7000);
    

      // res.download('/12345.pdf')    
      myDoc.end();

})
})

}

app.post('/accounting_download',urlencodedParser,db_admin.download1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pdfkit` использует шрифты встроенные в пакет, а не в операционную систему и судя по [этому ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718559/how-to-output-euro-symbol-in-pdfkit-for-nodejs), эти шрифты не поддерживаю русские символы. Но это легко можно обойти передав вместо параметра путь у шрифту.

Там же у метода `text` нет опции `lang` ([документация](http://pdfkit.org/docs/text.html#text_styling)).

И создавать файл, а потом его отправлять не обязательно, в метод `pipe` можно передать `res` и оно будет сразу писать в ответ.

Например, итоговый код будет создавать pdf с русскими символами:

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.contentType("application/pdf");

    let myDoc = new pdf();
    myDoc.pipe(res);

    // тут остальная генерация pdf ...
    
    // используем шрифт из файла (я его скопировал из ОС)
    myDoc.font('./Times New Roman.ttf')
         .text('почему не понимаешь кириллицу ?');
    myDoc.end();
});
```